# Include a condition to execute a sql query if another select statement meets the condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a problem executing a query. I have two sql queries that look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(clients_id) FROM users_clients WHERE users_id = 'sample';
```

And

```
SELECT name FROM clients JOIN users_clients ON clients.client_id = users_clients.clients_id WHERE users_clients.users_id = 123456;
```

I need to execute the second sql statement IF the first is equal or greater than 1. Can I perform this query in just one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT .... second_query
WHERE
   .....
   AND (
       SELECT COUNT(clients_id) FROM users_clients WHERE users_id = 'sample'
   ) > 1
```

If a result of the subquery <=1, then the whole query returns no rows. In fact, MySql will not run the main (second) query at all.

Comment: Oh God. That was so easy. Really thank you a lot krokodilko.

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists

```
  SELECT name 
  FROM clients 
  JOIN users_clients ON clients.client_id = users_clients.clients_id 
  WHERE users_clients.users_id = 123456
  and exists(
    SELECT COUNT(clients_id) 
    FROM users_clients 
    WHERE users_id = 'sample'
    )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM clients 
JOIN users_clients 
ON clients.client_id = users_clients.clients_id 
WHERE users_clients.users_id = 123456
AND (SELECT COUNT(clients_id) FROM users_clients WHERE users_id = 'sample' ) > 1
```

Comment: Though this answer might help, it would be better if you would explain _how_ it works, to help the OP to understand and use the construct next time by her/himself